# Passing a Variable From Server To Client Lua

Tags: lua, fivem

Okay so I am trying to figure out a way to run a client function in my server function so I decided to run a client event in my server event to make it server script but I could not figure out how to take the variable needed in the client from the server here is my code in my server script

The error I am getting is `Attempt to index a nil value (local 'args')`
since I am not getting args from server and trying to use it in client just need a way to make the variable pass over from server to client

```
RegisterCommand("aspawn", function(source, args, raw)
    local src = source
    local animal = args[1]
    local Model = GetHashKey(animal)
    if IsPlayerAceAllowed(src, "DonnySpawner") then
        if not args[1] then
            print("Not Args 1 or 0") else
            TriggerClientEvent("DonnySpawner:command", src)
            Citizen.Wait(5000)
    if not HasModelLoaded(Model) then
        print("Could not load")
    else

    local Ped = PlayerPedId()
    local PedPosition = GetEntityCoords(Ped, false)

    Deer.Handle = CreatePed(28, Model, PedPosition.x, PedPosition.y, PedPosition.z, GetEntityHeading(Ped), true, false)

    SetPedCanRagdoll(Deer.Handle, Deer.Ragdoll)
    SetEntityInvincible(Deer.Handle, Deer.Invincible)

    SetModelAsNoLongerNeeded(Model)
          end
       end
    end
end)
```

And this is my client function

```
RegisterNetEvent("DonnySpawner:command")
AddEventHandler("DonnySpawner:command", function(source, args, raw)
    local src = source
    local animal = args[1]
    local Model = GetHashKey(animal)
    RequestModel(Model)
end)
```